# Hql: How to goup time by 30 minutes

Tags: group-by, hive, hiveql

I need an Hql query that gives as an output time grouped by 30 minutes. I did a lot of reseaches I only found queries in Sql , I tried the following ones:

```
 SELECT date_format(`date`, "YYYY-MM-dd hh:00:00.000 aa"),dateadd(minute,(datediff(minute,0,a.dt)/30)*30,0) FROM flux GROUP BY dateadd(minute,(datediff(minute,0,a.dt)/30)*30,0)
```

it gives me the following error:

```
Invalid function dateadd
```

I tried also this one:

```
 SELECT  date_format(`date`, "YYYY-MM-dd hh:00:00.000 aa") FROM flux GROUP BY second(`date`)%('30*60')
```

But it gives me the folowing error:

```
 Error encountered near token ''30*60''
```

if you have any Idea on how I can solve my issue please HELP.

THANK YOU !

Comment: Can you post sample data?

Comment: yes sure when I run SELECT  `date`  FROM flux it  gives

Comment: 2018-01-26 12:14:36
2018-01-26 12:14:49
2018-01-26 12:14:54
2018-01-26 12:30:42
2018-01-26 12:30:51
7  2018-01-26 12:31:51
8  2018-01-26 12:31:55
9  2018-01-26 12:31:59
10  2018-01-26 12:34:25
11  2018-01-26 12:34:30
12  2018-01-26 18:34:29

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to seconds and divide it by 30*60 and use group by.

[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/105981)

```
select from_unixtime(round(unix_timestamp(ts)/1800)*1800),count(*) as count_30,
from flux
group by round(unix_timestamp(ts)/1800)
```

Comment: Thank you for relpying, but it gives the following error

Comment: cannot recognize input near 'from_unixtime' '(' 'round' in expression specification

Comment: cannot recognize input near 'from_unixtime' '(' 'unix_timestamp' in expression specification

Comment: Please what does count(*) mean?